# Add a map for each node in a view

Tags: views, google-maps, location

I am building a restaurant application which would have a search functionality, and when somebody searches of restaurants for a zip code, it would return the data. The data would be the name of the restaurant, the description and the map. When a user is adding the restaurant, I am using address field and geofield to get the latitude and longitude, so getting the maps up and running isn't an issue now.

However, I trying to create the search view, but I am unable to create a view which has a path, and which would display the title, description and then the map.

```
ex: Title | Description
    MAP1(map for first restaurant)

    Title | Description
    MAP2
```

Can somebody tell me how would I build it?

The modules I am using to build this are geofield, geophp, geocoder, addressfield, openlayers, views, ctools and libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1

Install and enable the [Geofield Map](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield_map) module. Create a view with the Geofield (latitude and longitude) fields with a contextual filter node ID. Change *Formatter* to *Geofield Map*.

> [image: screenshot]

#### Step 2

Install and enable the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. Create another view for the restaurant details. For viewing the map, you can select *Global: view* in the field. You then select which view to embed in that field and give the arguments it requires in the field settings.

> [image: screenshot]